# Counter example: $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ continuous with a unique global minimum does not imply that $f$ is coercive

Tags: real-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

I want to answer the question whether a continuous function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ with a unique global minimum has to be coercive.

Intuitively, that is, of course, false. I'm imagining a symmetrical function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that behaves similar to a parabola around the origin and then curves outwards such that $f(x) \to 1$ as $\lvert x\rvert\ \to \infty$.

However, I'm having trouble to find an explicit formula for that kind of function. How can I do this?

Are there, in general, any useful tips or strategies to construct a specific function with certain desired analytical qualities (e.g. extrema, limits etc.)?

Comment: try $\exp(-\lVert x\rVert^{-2})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the negative of the multivariate Gaussian distribution. It has a global minimum at the mean and goes to zero at extremes.

Comment: That's a good idea, but my question still remains: How to cook up such a function from scratch?